# System.Net.WebException: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made

Tags: ios, ssl, xamarin.forms, webexception

Already found the same thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755674/ios9-getting-error-an-ssl-error-has-occurred-and-a-secure-connection-to-the-ser), but that not resolved my problem.

I have added `NSAppTransportSecurity` and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in info.plist.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Added the below codes from [this](https://medium.com/@YogevSitton/how-to-fix-ios-9-ats-ssl-error-when-your-server-supports-tls-version-1-2-fd93b219853e) article.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>pm-admin.smartwcm.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

**I am using HTTP REST APIs.** When running the project I am getting the following exception:

> System.Net.WebException: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?

**Am I missing something or do anything wrong?**

Comment: Is the SSL certificate valid? Is it connecting to the hostname on the certificate? Is the certificate self-issued? If you open the url in your browser do you get any prompts related to the certificate?

Comment: @Maximilian I have the same rest apis in another app which is already in appstore. This is a public rest api and no problems if it open in a browser..

Comment: @Maximilian All my REST APIs are HTTP, If I change it into HTTPS is that work?

Comment: That would most likely resolve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cause:** Since iOS 9, iOS will only allow your application to communicate with servers that implement best-practice security by default. Values must be set in Info.plist to enable communication with insecure servers.It seems that you only `AllowInsecureHTTPSLoads` but forget to add `AllowsInsecureHTTPLoads`

**Solution:** Add the following code in your info.plist to trust your domain.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
 <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
 <dict>
  <key>pm-admin.smartwcm.com</key>
  <dict>       
   <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
   <false/>
   <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
   <true/>
   <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
   <true/>
   ...... 
  </dict>
 </dict>
```

Here is [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032699/uiwebview-in-xamarin-ios-seems-to-ignore-external-css-styles) that you can refer.

Comment: Getting following exception when adding the above code:
System.Net.WebException: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be â€œpm-admin.smartwcm.comâ€ which could put your confidential information at risk. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be â€œpm-admin.smartwcm.comâ€ which could put your confidential information at risk."

Comment: Can you share your sample?

Comment: I created this sample last weak, so didn't add the code in info.plist, can you please add it?

Comment: It seems that your sample contains your userName and password .I suggest that you should delete it to prevent privacy breaches.

Comment: I will try your demo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187836/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).

Comment: Hi @SreejithSree did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Irshad As per Lucas's answer, I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you must to use certificate.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionDelegate,URLSessionTaskDelegate {

var urlSession: Foundation.URLSession!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        urlSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
}

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust
        let certificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust!, 0)
        let policies = NSMutableArray();
        policies.add(SecPolicyCreateSSL(true, (challenge.protectionSpace.host as CFString)))
        SecTrustSetPolicies(serverTrust!, policies);
        var result: SecTrustResultType = SecTrustResultType(rawValue: 0)!
        SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust!, &result)
        let isServerTrusted:Bool = (result == SecTrustResultType.unspecified || result == SecTrustResultType.proceed)
        let remoteCertificateData:NSData = SecCertificateCopyData(certificate!)
        let pathToCert = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "certificateName", ofType: "crt")
        let localCertificate:NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToCert!)!
        let credential:URLCredential = URLCredential(trust: serverTrust!)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)

    }


}
```

Comment: On where I need to add this class? I try to add a class to the ios project but getting a lot of errors. Is any NuGet package need to install?

Comment: when you need to use URLSession you must add URLSessionDelegate,URLSessionTaskDelegate to your viewController and don't miss your certificate File .crt in your Project

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, can you please explain?

Comment: All my REST APIs are HTTP, If I change it into HTTPS is that work?